# Javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'removeNode'"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting JavaScript error on Chrome like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'removeNode'
```

and my code is

```
if (document.form["act[" + actArry["'" + i + "'"][i] + "]"] != undefined)
    document.form["act[" + actArry["'" + i + "'"][i] + "]"].removeNode(true);
```

and a value which is stored in that `input` element is

```
<input type="hidden" name="act[1]" value="7813e7-true">
```

Actually I want to remove `-true` when `checkbox` is `unchecked`.

This is working properly in IE but not in Google Chrome.

Can anybody tell me what is the issue and which should be the common method in both IE and Chrome? Is there an alternative in jQuery?

Comment: If you just want to change the _value_ of the input, no need to remove it. You can change its `.value` to whatever you want.

Comment: You can drop the `"'"` from the control name expression and the ` != undefined` from the test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`removeNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an IE only method. It will not work in other browsers.

You can do a [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) *on the parent node* to achieve the same along with being cross browser.

i.e.:

```
if (node.parentNode)
   node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Ref: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?126312-Mozilla-equivalent-for-IE-s-removeNode()

Comment: [`.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) should be used. Worth mentioning that `.remove` just made it into the DOM api 2 weeks ago so we might have similar functionality in the future :)

Comment: +1 from me too. I appreciate your very fast reply and it's working like charm :) And you explained it thoroughly and also thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum for detail info

Comment: Good, but `.removeNode()` also accepts an argument, the `.removeChild()` workaround doesn't touch on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use removeChild, it works in most browsers.